# R: Count frequency of values in nested list with sub-elements

Tags: r, list, frequency, nested-lists

I have a nested list that contains country names.
I want to count the frequency of the countries, whereby +1 is added with each mention in a sub-list (regardless of how often the country is mentioned in that sub-list).

For instance, if I have this list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Austria" "Austria" "Austria"

[[2]]
[1] "Austria" "Sweden"

[[3]]
[1] "Austria" "Austria" "Sweden"  "Sweden" "Sweden" "Sweden"

[[4]]
[1] "Austria" "Austria" "Austria"

[[5]]
[1] "Austria" "Japan"
```

... then I would like the result to be like this:

```
country        freq
====================
Austria         5
Sweden          2
Japan           1
```

I have tried various ways with `lapply`, `unlist`, `table`, etc. but nothing worked the way I would need it. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way with `lapply()`, `unlist()` and `table()`:

```
count <- table(unlist(lapply(lst, unique)))
count
# Austria   Japan  Sweden 
#       5       1       2 


as.data.frame(count)
#      Var1 Freq
# 1 Austria    5
# 2   Japan    1
# 3  Sweden    2
```

Reproducible data (please provide yourself next time):

```
lst <- list(
  c('Austria', 'Austria', 'Austria'), 
  c("Austria", "Sweden"), 
  c("Austria", "Austria", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden"), 
  c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria"), 
  c("Austria", "Japan")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to get data in dataframe format and count unique elements where each country occurs.

```
library(dplyr)

tibble::enframe(lst) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(value) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(freq = n_distinct(name))


# value    freq
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 Austria     5
#2 Japan       1
#3 Sweden      2
```

**data**

```
lst <- list(c('Austria', 'Austria', 'Austria'), c("Austria", "Sweden"), 
     c("Austria", "Austria", "Sweden",  "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden"), 
     c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria"), c("Austria", "Japan" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R option

```
colSums(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      lst,
      function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(lst)))) > 0
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
Austria  Sweden   Japan
      5       2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to `stack` into a two column data.frame, then take the `unique` and apply the `table`

```
table(unique(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))))$values)

#   Austria   Japan  Sweden 
#     5       1       2
```